# Draw tree Layout chart in vega

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I want to have a tree chart of my data using vega in kibana 7.9.0, but I don't know how to write the query for that.
the below code is an example of tree chart from github website. I want such layout for my own index which I have it in kibanan.

Help me how to do that.

[tree chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X45NG.png)

Sample tree chart code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "An example of Cartesian layouts for a node-link diagram of hierarchical data.",
  "width": 1000,
  "height": 1600,
  "padding": 5,

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "labels", "value": true,
      "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}
    },
    {
      "name": "layout", "value": "tidy",
      "bind": {"input": "radio", "options": ["tidy", "cluster"]}
    },
    {
      "name": "links", "value": "diagonal",
      "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "options": ["line", "curve", "diagonal", "orthogonal"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "separation", "value": false,
      "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "tree",
      "url": "data/flare.json",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "stratify",
          "key": "id",
          "parentKey": "parent"
        },
        {
          "type": "tree",
          "method": {"signal": "layout"},
          "size": [{"signal": "height"}, {"signal": "width - 100"}],
          "separation": {"signal": "separation"},
          "as": ["y", "x", "depth", "children"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "links",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [
        { "type": "treelinks" },
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "shape": {"signal": "links"}
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {"scheme": "magma"},
      "domain": {"data": "tree", "field": "depth"},
      "zero": true
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "links"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "path": {"field": "path"},
          "stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "tree"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {"value": 100},
          "stroke": {"value": "#fff"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "depth"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "tree"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"field": "name"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 9},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "dx": {"signal": "datum.children ? -7 : 7"},
          "align": {"signal": "datum.children ? 'right' : 'left'"},
          "opacity": {"signal": "labels ? 1 : 0"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add what have you tried in elasticsearch/kibana. The code you add in your question doesn't show your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: The above code is an example of tree chart from github so istead of that I want to use my data source from my own index for example I have index by the name of 123 and iside that there are alot of fields but I only want to show me the relationship between two fields A party and B party. In A party there is only one number and in B party there are alot of numbers so how do I create such query for that to show me the relationship between these two fields in tree chart

Answer (score 1):

I recommend going and learning the Kibana Vega interaction, Vega spec and elasticsearch search api. This is too broad of a question, you are basically asking someone to do the work for you which is easily deducible from the the documentation.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/vega.html

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html